# open Excel file in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch

i just want to know about a solution for opening an excel in **'sencha touch'**. is it possible, if there is any applications installed in device that support excel, through code.

regards,

Sivajith S.

Comment: Do you need to generate the file client-side or can you just provide the file from the server? If the device on which your app is running has an app that supports Excel documents, then providing a link to the Excel file may suffice; depends on your precise requirements. In that case make sure the server reports the correct MIME type, application/vnd.ms-excel.

Comment: @Will: i generated the excel file in sever side, but not finding any way to read the same.... do you have any code sample with you...!!!!!!!?

Comment: If the user's device already has an app that reads Excel, then an HTML link such as <a href="url-of-file-here">download</a> should do it. If you cannot guarantee that your users can read raw Excel, then can you have the server parse Excel and render JSON or HTML instead? That would probably be easier than implementing an Excel reader client side.

Comment: @Will : The user actually want to see the data as excel itself. So I just want to open up the excel file to the user.

Comment: If anybody can provide any code snippet it will be really helpful..

Comment: In that case something as simple as <a href="url-of-file-here">download</a> should do it. Again, this assumes the user has an Excel-compatible application. In your client you will merely have to supply the appropriate URL and test that the server delivers the file correctly. Can your server do this, or can you get it changed to do this? For help with the server side, we'll need to know what platform it is. Java/Tomcat, Python, Rails...? The main thing is it needs to deliver the file using MIME type application/vnd.ms-excel as I mentioned.